# Função em Ionic 3

Tags: typescript, ionic3

Estou fazendo uma função no arquivo `TS` da página, mas precisaria capturar as informações do HTML para fazer uma condicional de `push(navCtrl)` para cada opção...

A lista no qual preciso pegar as informações e o código:

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Ocupação</ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="ocupacao">
          <ion-option value="dir" >Diretor(a)</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="prof">Professor(a)</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="res">Responsável</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="sec">Secretária</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com o two-way data binding você pode acessar à variável no .ts como this.ocupacao, então digamos que ao chamar um submit a função onSubmit abaixo é executada

```
onSubmit = () =>{
  //acessando à variável ocupacao
  console.log(this.ocupacao);
  if(this.ocupacao == 'dir')
     this.navCtrl.push(DirPage);
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado !!